# Meteor + cordova-ios. Error: Cannot find module ‘./util.js’

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, meteor

**Meteor 1.3.2.4.**

I got this error everytime I try to `meteor run` / `meteor run ios-device` a project with cordova-ios.

Log:

```
/Users/admin/Desktop/My-App/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:324
}).run(); 
   ^ 
Error: Cannot find module './util.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object. (/Users/admin/.meteor/packages/babel-compiler/.6.6.4.1vgwjcg++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-babel/cache.js:4:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Do you have any thoughts what can cause that issue?

**UPDATE:** This happens only on MAC, on WIN everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing Meteor solved this issue.